# Excel:comparing two columns and return matched value in a single cell

Tags: excel

I'm trying to match two columns and get the matched value in a single cell.
For eg.

> Column 1 - 8, 5, 7, AA, 10
>
> Column2  - AA, DET, V, H, PED

```
8    AA
5    DET
7    V
AA   H
10   PED
```

Value returned - AA (This is the value that i want to get since this is common in both columns)

I tried using Index and match functions, but they are not able to match the two given range. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if column 2 also had the value of 10? Are you expecting only one match? are you expecting the matching values to be comma separated?

Comment: Yes i am just looking for one match

Comment: Column 1 contains only numbers and there can only be at most one matching string from column 2 to column 1. Column two is fixed and no value gonna change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you want is this array formula:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$5,MATCH(TRUE,COUNTIF($B$1:$B$5,$A$1:$A$5)>0,0))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of just Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Avoid full column references with Array formulas as their calculations are exponential.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot . I tried it and worked. I would look more into the formula to learn about it. Thanks a lot again! :-)

Comment: Can I get 'N/A' value when nothing matches up?

Comment: This seems to only work for me if the matching value is in B1, if not, it returns the last value in the list.

Comment: Does this works only for the given position of AA in column?

Comment: @Navy see edit, I forgot to make the match look for exact.  If this answers your question please mark it as correct by clicking the green check mark.

Comment: It wasn't working in all situations until you fixed the exact match.

Comment: Yup, it was not till I looked into the no `#N/A` issue that I realized it.  Thanks @WyattShipman

Comment: Np, I noticed it but didn't think about mentioning it. @ScottCraner

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying doubts. I fixed it.