# How Can I Compare Two Columns and Return the Matched Values in a Single Cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37886897/excelcomparing-two-columns-and-return-matched-value-in-a-single-cell) addresses a similar question, however it only returns the first matched value into the cell.

Their proposed formula was:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$5,MATCH(TRUE,COUNTIF($B$1:$B$5,$A$1:$A$5)>0,0))
```

What I'm looking for is adding multiple matched values into a single cell from those two columns, so:

Let:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| A | F |
| B | B |
| F | H |

The result in Column C should be:

| Column C |
| --- |
| Matched: B, F |

If there were no matched values, then we can leave it blank.

Comment: what version do you have?

Comment: @ScottCraner Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2211 Build 16.0.15831.20098) 32-bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using FILTER:

```
="Matched: "&TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER(A1:A3,ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1:A3,B1:B3,0))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Scott! How would you go about adding the "Match: " text if there were values to join?